# How do i get my Azure DevOps release pipeline to get artifacts from Azure Storage Account

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, nuget-package, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-storage-files

Im using Azure DevOps and have setup a "Release" pipeline, not a "Build" pipeline, and I want Release Pipeline to get is Artifacts from my Azure Storage Accounts.

The Artifacts have already been built and are Nuget package (.nupkg) files. I have copied them into an Azure Storage Account as File Storage. All they need to do is be use by a release pipeline.

So my question is how do I get my Azure Release Pipeline to get these files and use them in the Release?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't any native way to download automatically the binaries from a storage at the beginning of the release, you will have to add your own tasks to download it from the release (and add the connection string as a variables).

The usual pattern to share generated files between a build and a release is to use an [Azure DevOps Artifact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/build-artifacts?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml). You will need to add a the "Publish Build Artifacts" task to your build and then you will be able to link it to your release by clicking "+ Add" on the artifact panel.

Comment: YellowPill, did this help you? Do you need more information?